# Perl signal handling truncates connections to DB and causes errors

Tags: linux, database, oracle, perl

I have been tasked with writing a Perl script (perl v 5.8 - is what my company uses) that moves files from a file system to another and it updates the location of each file in the Oracle DB version 11R2.

I can move the files Ok. I update the DB Ok. 
I have not been able to get the script to end gracefully when a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> signal is received.
The reason for this is that when the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed while the script is connecting to the database. It immediately terminates the connection and an error code is returned before the query is executed.

I have tried to follow what several books and online publications suggest to handle the signals yet it doesnt seem to solve the issue. Usually it takes a few tries to reproduce it but eventually I manage to get the error condition.

I'm providing below some snapshots of my code.

```
#!/usr/local/PERL/bin/perl -w
my $STOP_SIGNAL = 0;
$SIG{INT}  = \&Shutdown_Handler;
$SIG{KILL} = \&Shutdown_Handler;
# I handle other signals too. No child processes on this script.

while ( $STOP_SIGNAL == 0 ) {
   # Find some files
   # Move some files
   # Update DB with file new location and close db connection
   # Establish a separate DB connecion to double check the transaction.
}

if ($STOP_SIGNAL) {
   print "EXIT DUE TO Ctrl-C SIGNAL\n";
} else {
   print "NORMAL EXIT\n";
}

sub Shutdown_Handler() {
   $STOP_SIGNAL ++;
   return;
}
```

Has anyone come across this? How did you solve it?
Thanks Dan.

Environment:

```
PERL:
  perl -version
  This is perl, v5.8.1 built for i686-linux
DATABASE:
  Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
  With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, in my example it's good work for me. (perl 5.18.2)

```
my $stop = 0;

$SIG{INT} = sub { ++$stop; };

while (!$stop) {
      print "live\n";
      sleep 1;
}

print "exit by signal" if ($stop);
```

Comment: That part works for me as well. If I had no connections to the database I wouldn't really have an issue at all. The problem is that when the script receives the Ctrl-C signal the connection to the DB is affected and the query that is currently executing reports false errors. If I could prevent the Ctrl-C signal from causing this it would be sweet.